# PostgreSQL URL query subsitution

Tags: postgresql

It has been a long time since I've used SQL and I need to execute a COPY to retrieve a .csv from a website and the URL must be altered for each query.  How could this be done/is it possible?  Everything I've tried has failed.

Something like this-

```
http://abc.zyx/xyz?a=[sub from a column]/
```

Comment: You have shown us the URL but how do you want it altered?

Comment: `http://abc.zyx/xyz?a=**[SUB FROM A COLUMN]**`